# Radiobutton does not run definition

Tags: python, user-interface, radio-button, tkinter

I'm working with a GUI for my program. The code looks like this:

```
lijst=[]
def setValueTrue():
    del lijst[0:len(lijst)]
    e2="True"
    lijst.append(e2)
    print lijst[0]

def setValueFalse():
    del lijst[0:len(lijst)]
    e2="False"
    lijst.append(e2)
    print lijst[0]

lijst1=[]
def setValueTrue1():
    del lijst1[0:len(lijst1)]
    e2="True"
    lijst1.append(e2)

def setValueFalse1():
    del lijst1[0:len(lijst1)]
    e2="False"
    lijst1.append(e2)


root = Tk()
var = IntVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1,
                  command=setValueTrue())
R1.pack(anchor = W)
R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=2,
                  command=setValueFalse())
R2.pack(anchor = W)
R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 3", variable=var, value=3,
                  command=setValueTrue1())
R3.pack(anchor = W)

R4 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 4", variable=var, value=4,
                  command=setValueFalse1())
R4.pack(anchor = W)

b=Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
b.pack()
b=Button(root, text='Oke', command=lambda:tekenGraaf("OutputB1.txt",25,0.8,dimensies=3,kleur=str(lijst[0]),groepen=str(lijst1[0])))
b.pack()
mainloop()
```

I have 4 radiobuttons. These create with the definitions the value true or false. This value i want to use in my 'big' definition. But when i click the radiobuttons, the defs (setValueTrue etc.) are not executed. Only when i run the program the radiobuttons run the def's. FOr this reasons the values of list and list1 automatically become false and false. Does anyone know why the radiobuttons aren't running the code.

Answer (score 1):

The `command` option takes a *reference* to a function. When you do `command=setValueTrue()` you are *calling* the function, and giving the result of the function to the `command` attribute. The result is `None`, so there is no command associated with the button.

The fix is to remove the parenthesis:

```
R1 = Radiobutton(..., command=setValueTrue, ...)
```